# SharePoint 2013 branding issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, master-page, custom-masterpage, branding

I am creating MaterPage from html page. In the page there is link tag for css which **data-skrollr-stylesheet** as it don't have equal sign it gives error. How can we add that.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sk_sheet.css" data-skrollr-stylesheet />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **scripts tags** right before the closing **Body** tag, include the `skrollr.stylesheet.min.js` file followed by the `skrollr.js`.

See below:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src="dist/skrollr.stylesheets.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="js/skrollr.js"></script>
```

You will get some more info from [here](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr).

Comment: Sorry but I am talking about css and you gave me js solution. Will it help me are you sure about that !!

Comment: You need to add these scripts, it helps your css to work. See this example: http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/docu/1.html

Answer (score 0):

In Html page

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/sites/gskglobal/mcLaren-partnership/Documents/live.css" />
```

In master page

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="Themable/oslo.css" runat="server" EnableCssTheming="true" />
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="/Style Library/Custom.css" After="corev15.css" runat="server" />
```